# How to add UI Kits (e.g. Google Material) to Adobe Experience Design?

Tags: android, adobe, user-experience

I installed Adobe XD (Experience Design) for UI/UX design in Android and noticed there are UI Kits for different platforms. When I click on them, instead of opening them like what I saw in many different online tutorials it just opens the web page to download. What is wrong? Or is there something wrong?

I use windows 10 build 15063.608.

[UI Kits menu inside Hamburger menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO6zX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer made by an Adobe staff on their forum [here](https://forums.adobe.com/message/9829391#9829391), this option is no longer available and you have to download it from the source and open it like any other file so that Apple, Google, and Microsoft will be able to keep the UI Kits up-to-date.

Comment: The resource files can also be opened by dragging them to an open XD window. ;-)